# How to remove and re-set focus on input when hovering over other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, setfocus

I use Bootstrap 3 and have a standard input field that looks as follows on which I set focus via jQuery on pageload:

**My Input:** `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchTerm" />`

**My jQuery:** `$('#searchTerm').focus();`

On the same page I have a Bootstrap navbar and would like to remove the above focus when navigating on the navbar + re-set the focus when leaving the navbar. The reason for this is that otherwise the blinking cursor is overlapping my navbar dropdowns so it is visible in the dropdown background.

**My Navbar:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header margin-right-30">
          // ...
```

I guess you can do this using focus / blur events on the class `"navbar"` but I wasn't sure if and how to realise this. How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use jQuery's [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) methods (documentation in links).  Note that the `.hover()` method takes a callback argument which is a function that will be called when the event happens.  The `.focus` method, however, while it can take a callback method, can be called without arguments to simply change the focus to the element left of the dot.

For example you may want to do something like the following:

```
$('#navBar').hover(function(){
  this.focus();
});
```